# make api call for each item of array

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, angular-services, angular-httpclient

I have an array of object of days, I want to make separate HTTP call for each array item. but the condition is when I get the previous items success response then only I want to make next items API request till I want to wait. suppose I have 5 items in my array so it will make API call immediately. I want that each items API request sequentially. means when my first items API requests response is true then second items API should call.

I have used a for & for each loop and traverse each array item & make HTTP post call but it don't wait for previous requests success response.

```js
// component call

daysArr = [
    {
      day: 'Monday',
      date: '20-10-2018'
    },
    {
      day: 'Tuesday',
      date: '21-10-2018'
    },
    {
      day: 'Wednesday',
      date: '22-10-2018'
    },
    {
      day: 'Thursday',
      date: '23-10-2018'
    },
    {
      day: 'Friday',
      date: '24-10-2018'
    },
    {
      day: 'Saturday',
      date: '25-10-2018'
    },
    {
      day: 'Sunday',
      date: '26-10-2018'
    }
  ]
  
  postCall() {
  let apiUrl = 'https:someurl.com/api/dayspost';
  for (let i = 0; i < this.daysArr.length; i++) {
  
      // how to check previous request response & make request for next array element
      
    this.service.createPost(apiUrl,this.daysArr[i])
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log('response',response)
    })
  }
}

//service post call

createPost(url, post) {
   return this.http.post(url,post)
    .pipe(
      map(data => {
        return data;
      })
     )
 }
```

above is the snippet which displays the API request. but I don't understand how can I check my previous response & then only make new API/post call for new array element.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
let i = 0;
makeRequest(apiUrl, this.daysArr[i]){
  this.service.createPost(apiUrl,post)
    .subscribe(response => {
       console.log('response',response)
       i++;
       if(i < this.days.length){
          makeRequest(apiUrl, this.daysArr[i])
       }
  })
}
```

I have no IDE right now to try this, but it should work fine